# A Java Threading wait() and Notify() seems to work peculiarly

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class myThreadRun implements Runnable
{

    public void run() {
        roo();
    }
    public synchronized void roo()
    {
        System.out.println("In thread before wait " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "After wait in\n"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("In thread after wait " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        //notify();
    }

    public synchronized void foo()
    {
        notify();
    }
}

public class ThreadingDemo {

    public synchronized void Start()
    {
        System.out.println("Labamba");
        myThreadRun mThRun =  new myThreadRun();
        Thread thread =  new Thread(mThRun);
        thread.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //mThRun.foo(); //This works
        //mThRun.notify(); //crash
        //thread.notify();//crash
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
public static  void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadingDemo().Start();
    }
```

This is simple code to demonstrate wait() and notify(), 
In the myThreadRun class run() method just does wait() and foo() method does notify()
as indicated in the code above, if I do mThRun.notify() the program crashes, but mThRun.foo() runs the without a hitch and gives the much needed result. I need to know why?

Comment: I don't think it is the issue, but you should *always* use `wait()` in a loops. From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29): `As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop: `

Comment: Java documentation is as follows:

Comment: Also: please provide a complete stack trace, it will help understand the problem better.

Comment: Exception in thread "The Main Thread" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at ThreadingDemo.Start(ThreadingDemo.java:78)
        at ThreadingDemo.main(ThreadingDemo.java:101)

Answer (score 2):

You need to own the monitor for the object to all `obj.wait()` and `obj.notify()`.

That is why it works when called within the `synchronized` block on `mThRun` but not outside. So if you put the `mThRun.notify();` in a synchronized block, it works, like this:

```
synchronized (mThRun) {
    mThRun.notify();
}
```

Comment: The methods were wait() and notify() are used are synchronized

Comment: @amit, you need to own the objects monitor he is synchronizing on the wrong object.

Comment: He is doing `wait()` and `notify()`, which is implicitly `this.wait()` and `this.notify()`. And the methods are synchronized, so it is implicitly `syncrhonized(this)`

Comment: @amit, No (or maybe I just read the question wrong) but that works! It's the `mThRun.notify()` (commented) that crashes the program since he is just doing synchronization on the `ThreadingDemo` object..

Comment: Oh. Yes, I think you are correct, I misunderstood the question. I thought he had some problem with the non-commented out notify().

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are getting an [IllegalMonitorStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html).

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

Put another way, you don't hold the lock of the object you are trying to notify.  Having the lock of a different object doesn't help.

---

When you use notify() and wait() you need to change a state and check for it.  If you don't do this, you can find that either

- notify() is called before wait() and the signal is lost
- wait() wakes prematurely

You cannot assume notify/wait is a reliable messaging protocol.

I suggest you consider using the concurrency library which is a better choice in most cases from Java 5.0 (2004)

Comment: @user1629315 Ran your program, read the error and updated my answer. Helpfully this helps.

Comment: When foo() is called from Start() the foo() function runs under  context of the Start()'s thread (which is the main() thread). So When notify() is called directly the same is happening, but the program crashes.

Comment: Your foo() is synchronized for the object which you are are calling notify() on. When I do this, it doesn't crash. When you use notify() directly on the objects you don't hold a lock for you should expect to get an Exception as documented.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are going very hard with wait/notify. Its very simple. what you need to know is which object is used for monitor lock. To make the same code working i have modified the same code: ( I have put MAK comment where i changed the code, hope its helpful)

```
class MyThreadRun implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        roo();
    }
    public synchronized void roo() {
        System.out.println("In thread before wait " + this);
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "After wait in\n" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("In thread after wait " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}

public class ThreadingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThreadRun mThRun = new MyThreadRun();
        System.out.println("Labamba: " +mThRun);
        Thread thread = new Thread(mThRun);
        thread.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //mThRun.foo(); //This works  //MAK: no sense
        //mThRun.notify(); //crash   //MAK: Need monitor lock
        synchronized (mThRun) {
            mThRun.notify();//crash                  //MAK: will work now
        }
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```